# Objective differences between running NetworkManager and changing resolv.conf

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, dns

Are there any objective differences between running `NetworkManager` and changing `resolve.conf` in the following manners? See method #1 and method #2 below. They appear to produce identical results in Ubuntu 18.04.

### Method 1: `resolv.conf`

```sh
sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
sudo gedit /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
# then added the google nameservers to my file, adding this line.
nameserver 8.8.8.8 # or 1.1.1.1
```

### Method 2: NetworkManager

[image: screenshot]

Comment: #1 changes the symlink for /etc/resolv.conf (to try and cure DNS resolution issues in 18.xx) and adds a nameserver (should use the DNS=) to systemd-resolve. #2 uses NetworkManager via a GUI to change the DNS servers. (*Note: you really should settle down a bit and consolidate all of your various network questions, down to one question, accompanied by a little research first*).

Comment: Also, when starting graphic applications from the terminal command line, use `sudo -H` instead of just `sudo`, or you may create a login loop for your username.